# I want a function that has child functions to access the same named function, without it depending the class of it's child class

Tags: c++, class, inheritance

So basically, I want my first class to be a basic one, just like in the example down below, to be inherited, and the child classes which come out of it, to have a same named function, that will return the fictional price of something, but I don't know how to access the functions while writing a void function out of classes, which recieves an array of pointers of the basic class and then the number of array elements, then calls for the same named function in both child classes.

Take a look yourself.

While you're at it, feel free to tell me any errors I've made along the way, regards!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

class basic{
protected:
    char name[20];
public:
    basic(char * n)
    {
        strcpy(name,n);
    }
};

class advanced1:public basic{
protected:
    float price;
public:
    advanced1(char * n, float p):basic(n)
    {
        price=p;
    }
    float priced()
    {
        if(price<10)
            return price*1.5;
        else
            return price*1.2;
    }
};

class advanced2:public basic{
protected:
    float price;
public:
    advanced2(char * n, float p):basic(n)
    {
        price=p;
    }
    float priced()
    {
        if(price<15)
            return price*2.3;
        else
            return price*1.8;
    }
};

void printstuff(basic *basics[], int basicsN)
{
    for(int i=0;i<basicsN;i++)
    {
        cout<<basics[i]->priced();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to implement a [virtual](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual) function in `basic`. By declaring a pure virtual function in `basic` and then implementing it in the derived classes, C++ will know the call `basics[i]->priced()` should call from derived classes.

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a "virtual" function. You can follow [this tutorial](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/virtual-function-cpp/).

Looking at your code, it seems like you don't actually want the base class to implement the function. For that you'd have to use a pure virtual function - [see this link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pure-virtual-functions-and-abstract-classes/). But keep in mind that using a pure virtual function means that you cannot directly instantiate the base class.

And about errors, just on first glance, the way you use `strcpy` could write beyond the end of the `name` array. I recommend using `strncpy` ([see this](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstring/strncpy/)) instead and specifying the number of characters. If you want to copy exactly 20 characters always, you could specify 20, or if 20 is just the limit, you could use `strlen` to get the length of the incoming string and then copy `std::min(20, length)` characters.

Comment: Thanks for the link, and by the way, the exercise I was given specifies that the name wouldn't be any longer than 20 characters, thanks again!